# Should I skip and take my LINQ query for grid view paging?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview

I m using LINQ select for filing gridview. My gridview is allow paging and its page size is 10;

now i write a query same as this :

```
var select=from res in db.tblusers select res;
grdUsers.DataSource=select;
grdUsers.DataBind();
```

my user table has about 1000 records.

Should I change my query to :

```
var select=(from res in db.tblusers select res).skip(pageIndex).take(PageSize)
```

Is it better or not?

Answer (score 3):

You should do a little correction in `skip` function

```
var select=(from res in db.tblusers select res).skip(pageIndex * PageSize).take(PageSize);
```

And of course, it should always be better to do server side paging than client side paging.

Comment: Now another problem. When I do it then gridview can not show paging numbers. Because in its datasource there aren't more than page size records. What should I do ?!!!

Comment: @Mehdi: In this case, you need to return the total row count from database and set this number to gridiview's datasource rowCount (or like) property.